# How to accomplish "AuthType None" in Apache 2.2

Tags: authentication, apache2.2

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authtype talks about "AuthType None", and has an awesome example of exactly what I need to do - unfortunately, it appears to be new to 2.3/2.4. Is there any equivalent feature in 2.2?

> The authentication type None disables
>   authentication. When authentication is
>   enabled, it is normally inherited by
>   each subsequent configuration section,
>   unless a different authentication type
>   is specified. If no authentication is
>   desired for a subsection of an
>   authenticated section, the
>   authentication type None may be used;
>   in the following example, clients may
>   access the /www/docs/public directory
>   without authenticating:
>
> ```
> <Directory /www/docs> 
> AuthType Basic
> AuthName Documents
> AuthBasicProvider file
> AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
> Require valid-user 
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory /www/docs/public>
> AuthType None
> Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```

Answer (score 102):

Something like below works for me with apache 2.2.  I took it from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require

```
<Directory /www/docs>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName Documents
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
    Require valid-user 
</Directory>
<Directory /www/docs/public>
    # All access controls and authentication are disabled
    # in this directory
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: @Technorati maybe you should consider accepting an answer already? This solution has worked fine for me so far.

Comment: If you want to allow certain files only, you can nest a Files directive under the parent Directory directive. It cannot be done with <Directory> though

Answer (score 9):

You just need to set Allow from all and Satisfy Any

This worked for me:

```
Alias /example "/opt/example.com"

<Directory "/opt/example.com">
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<Directory /www/docs/public>
AuthType None
Require all granted
Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

This will work

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add this bit of info:

On Apache 2.2.22 you need to have the order correct for it to work:

This did not work for me for location "/foo/sub":

```
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
```

I.e the authentication from the location "/foo" defined prior to "/foo/sub" still was applied.

This does work for location "/foo/sub":

```
Allow from all
Satisfy Any
```

I.e. the authentication from the location "/foo" defined prior to "/foo/sub" was annulled.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right: it is not supported in apache 2.2.

I would try the ugly workaround at https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10932

Something like:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/www/docs/(?!public)"> 
AuthType Basic
AuthName Documents
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
Require valid-user 
</Directory>
```

or

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/www/docs/[^p][^u][^b][^l][^i][^c]"> 
AuthType Basic
AuthName Documents
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
Require valid-user 
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on apache2.2:

```
    <Location /trac>
       #....
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "BLA domain"
       AuthUserFile /etc/.passwd
       Require valid-user
       Allow from all
       Satisfy Any
    </Location>
```