# apache 2.2: no authentication in subdirectory

Tags: authentication, apache2

I am running apache 2.2 on a linux machine and my goal is to have all directories except for a subdirectory with authentification. I can get the "all" directories to work, but when I add the except for the subdirectory, I get an internal error:

```
configuration error:  couldn't check user.  No user file?: /download/public/
```

This is my configuration file:

```
<Directory /var/www/mydir/software/download/public>
     AuthType None
     Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/mydir/software>
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName download
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/auth/software
      Require valid-user
 </Directory>
```

when I comment out the first four lines, everything works fine. With these lines, I get the aforementioned error.

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu)
```

Question: what do I need to change to get the subdirectory without authentification with apache 2.2. I believe that the configuration above is for 2.4. Is that what I want possible with 2.2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to accomplish "AuthType None" in Apache 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641646/how-to-accomplish-authtype-none-in-apache-2-2) (according to accepted answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was already answered: see [this previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641646/how-to-accomplish-authtype-none-in-apache-2-2).
You might try the ["ugly workaround" listed in the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3560064/367456) to that previous question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I solved adding in the httpd.conf

```
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
```

Comment: This may be useful for others with a 2.4 configuration, but the question lists Apache 2.2 and it should be noted mod_authz_core was brought in on Apache 2.3 so this wouldn't work.