# How to configure directory with no authentication only for specified ip addresses

Tags: apache, configuration, directory

In `/` directory I'm using `AuthType SPNEGO`, but in one subdirectory I need to have no authentication, but to be accesible  just from listed ip addresses.
Here is current configuration of that directory:

```
<Directory /foo/bar>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.5
</Directory>
```

By adding `Satisfy Any` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6129284/1095710)) is directory accessible without authentication, but is accessible for all ip addresses, not just for that that are listed. How can I achieve that?

Configuration of `/`:

```
<Directory />
  AuthName "FOO"
  <IfDefine AUTH_SPNEGO>
    Krb5ServiceName HTTP
    AuthType SPNEGO
  </IfDefine>
  require valid-user
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Which version of Apache are you using?

Comment: I'm using Apache 2.2.27

Comment: You don't want password authentication for /foo/bar from other IPs than the specific ones, right?

Comment: @CélineAussourd: I don't want password authentication for /foo/bar at all, and accessible only for listed IPs

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<Directory /foo/bar>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.5
</Directory>

<DirectoryMatch /(?!foo/bar)>
  AuthName "FOO"
  <IfDefine AUTH_SPNEGO>
    Krb5ServiceName HTTP
    AuthType SPNEGO
  </IfDefine>
  require valid-user
  allow from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

/foo/bar is accessible only by the specific IP (1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3.5 in this example)

And we set the password authentication for / excluding /foo/bar

Comment: The problem is that I want to disable spnego authentication in this directory, but your solution doesn't make that.

Comment: Ah weird, it works for me. What happened in your case? What is not working?